# How to revert wordpress when "settings" in the admin panel have been changed to prepare transfer to a live site?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm having a problem with my Wordpress. When I transferred the database to a live site then tried to revert it back to its original state (local server) so I could edit the wordpress site again, the functions in the admin panel were not working normally. Example when I log in to the admin panel only a white space loads. No page was loaded.

Below are the steps I made so I could transfer my Wordpress to a live site. By the way, I am using AMPPS to edit the Wordpress site locally.

1.) Backed up the database in the PHPMYADMIN by exporting a gzipped file.

2.)  Went to the Dashboard > Settings > Changed the Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL):

3.) After I changed the settings, I exported another database file so it will come with the changed settings.

4.) Successfully transferred the live site.

Again, here are the steps I made so I can revert back my Wordpress settings in my local server:

1.) Dropped the database in the "PHPMYADMIN" console.

2.) Imported the back up database.

3.) Successfully imported the back up.

Although it was successfully imported, every time I log-in there is always an error where only a white page loads. Absolutely 0. How can I revert my Wordpress in my local server properly?

I hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Wordpress Address (URL): FROM "127.0.0.1/testsite" TO http://www.testsite.com

Site Address (URL): The same

3.)

Comment: "Only a white page" indicates a server error with display errors hidden. Check PHP Error log, or add "ini_set('display_errors','on');" in the index.php and run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by doing the following:

1.) Go to phpmyadmin and drop the current tables in the database. (check all > then drop)

2.) In the back-up database, go to WP_OPTIONS table.

3.) In the first page, you will see a website address - change it to the web address of your local server (eg. `http://127.0.0.1/mysite`)

4.) Go to "Page 2" of the WP_OPTIONS

5.) You will see another URL where it says "`http://www.mysite.com`" to your local server address - `http://127.0.0.1/mysite`.

6.) Refresh your browser and all done!